# How are if statement in .vimrc executed

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I was thinking of writing an **if** statement in .vimrc file for my requirement. However I am not sure how **if** statements are executed in .vimrc. Are they executed only once when vim is started or every time the **if** event occurs? for example I am planning to insert following code in .vimrc

```
"Check if the drop down menu is active
if pumvisible()
   "pass 'down' key to vim
   \<lt>Down>
endif
```

Will this **if** code be executed every time the pumvisible() is active in vim workspace or it won't work at all?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The `if` statements are only executed when the file is `:source`d (which happens automatically on startup) but to propose an alternative will require you to let us know what you intend to achieve.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I respectfully disagree with you. `if` is just a branching construct. It is executed when the block of code or function surrounding if gets executed.

Comment: You can disagree, that's fine, but it sounds like what you have isn't meeting your requirements. If you want to state your requirements then you'll get help meeting those requirements.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang I am trying to automatically highlight a item in the drop down list. I am using You Complete Me and the menu becomes visible when I type code but without any option highlighted. I want it the menu to come and have automatically highlight the item that closely matches to what I am typing.

Answer (score 4):

`if` is just a conditional.
It doesn't listen to events. 
You can read more about it [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/21.html)

Looking at your use case, I think **Autocommands** is the way to go
[This](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) is a good introduction to autocommands

Comment: Do you have an example where autocmd is used with pumvisible(). I am getting error that pumvisible() doesn't work with autocmnd